How can I modify a specific object structure at any location in a larger JSON object using `jq`?
Say I have this JSON:
{
  "lunch": {
    "time": "11 am",
    "food": {
      "is_pizza": true
    }
  },
  "snacks": [
    {
      "time": "2 pm",
      "food": {
        "is_pizza": true
      }
    },
    {
      "time": "3:30 pm",
      "food": {
        "is_pizza": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "dinner": {
    "time": "6 pm",
    "food": {
      "is_pizza": true
    }
  }
}

Now I want to go through and wherever I see "food" object, add a the same key-value pair:
{
  "lunch": {
    "time": "11 am",
    "food": {
      "is_pizza": true,
      "extra_cheese": true
    }
  },
  "snacks": [
    {
      "time": "2 pm",
      "food": {
        "is_pizza": true,
        "extra_cheese": true
      }
    },
    {
      "time": "3:30 pm",
      "food": {
        "is_pizza": true,
        "extra_cheese": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "dinner": {
    "time": "6 pm",
    "food": {
      "is_pizza": true,
      "extra_cheese": true
    }
  }
}

How can I do that in jq?

Using walk would be one way:
walk(select(objects | has("food")).food.extra_cheese = true)

Demo
Using .. would be another:
(.. | objects | select(has("food"))).food.extra_cheese = true

Demo

If you wanted to import and add the object {"extra_cheese": true} from outside, use the --argjson option:
jq --argjson new '{"extra_cheese": true}' '‌... .food += $new' file.json


Thanks for jqplay.org demo - I didn't know about that tool. What does .. do?

.. is called the Recursive Descent, and produces all values recursing down the document tree, starting from the node currently in context (which is the root in this case).

Could you unpack the last example (--argjson) a bit? I can't get that to run. Is ... a thing?

--argjson (see Invoking jq) takes a variable name (here new) and a JSON value (here {"extra_cheese": true}), both controllable from the calling shell. From within jq, you can then retrieve the value by using that variable (here $new). The ... should be replaced by one of the provided solutions until .food, e.g. jq --argjson var '{"extra_cheese": true}' 'walk(select(objects | has("food")).food += $var)' file.json or jq --argjson obj '{"extra_cheese": true}' '‌(.. | objects | select(has("food"))).food += $obj' file.json
